# Question about a way to interact with dictionary

Tags: c#

**Introduction**

I built a web crawler for a project. One of the variables parse from the website is the date. I thought that building a dictionary containing the month in French and the int associated with it.

The way that I saw the code going is.

1. **Scrape** the data from the website
2. var moisLettres
3. Find the variable in the dictionary
4. Return the number associated with it

So far, I built this code, I searched for a few hours but the concept of comparing a dictionary is a little bit confusing. I'm open to other solutions since I'm here to help. Feel free to correct me.

Dictionary:

```cs
IDictionary<string, int> dictMonth = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            dictMonth.Add("Janvier",1);
            dictMonth.Add("Février",2);
            dictMonth.Add("Mars",3);
            //Up to 12 months
```

Examples so far:

```cs
     foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> b in dictMonth) // 
                {
                    if (b.Value.Equals(e.MonthInLetters, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                        return /* The TValue associated */
                            
                  }
```

Ways I explored:

1. Using the date.time method to translate automatically the month in string to month in Int. Since the data scraped is in French, the code doesn't work.

FULL CODE 1/2  (Some variables are in French since it is my main language)

`
{
//Variables de bases
const string accountSid = "Private";
const string authToken = "Private";

```
        List<Date> lstDate = new List<Date>();
       
        string sMessage = "";

        //Création du dictionnaire 
        
        IDictionary<string, int> dictMois = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dictMois.Add("Janvier",1);
        dictMois.Add("Février",2);
        dictMois.Add("Mars",3);
        dictMois.Add("Avril",4);
        dictMois.Add("Mai",5);
        dictMois.Add("Juin",6);
        dictMois.Add("Juillet",7);
        dictMois.Add("Aout",8);
        dictMois.Add("Septembre",9);
        dictMois.Add("Octobre",10);
        dictMois.Add("Novembre",11);
        dictMois.Add("Décembre",12);

        // Initialisation 

        Date un = new Date("19 Septembre", "Inconnu", "----------- ");
        Date deux = new Date("26 Septembre", "Inconnu", "----------");
        Date trois = new Date("3 Octobre", "Inconnu", "-----------");
        Date quatre = new Date("10 Octobre", "Inconnu", "-----------");
        Date cinq = new Date("17 Octobre", "Inconu", "-----------");
        Date six = new Date("24 Octobre", "Inconnu", "-----------");

        lstDate.Add(un);
        lstDate.Add(deux);
        lstDate.Add(trois);
        lstDate.Add(quatre);
        lstDate.Add(cinq);
        lstDate.Add(six);

        //Captation des dates 

        foreach (Date d in lstDate)
        {
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(d.url);
            var xpathDate = "-----------";
            var locationDate = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpathDate);
            var dateEvenement = locationDate.InnerText;


            d.date = dateEvenement;
        }

        //Vérification si les données sont exactes. 

        foreach (Date e in lstDate)
        {
         The way it works 

        // The data parse is "jeu., 19 septembre 2019"
        //un.date = "jeu., 19 septembre 2019"

        // un.annee = "jeu., 19 septembre 2019"
        // un.annee = (un.date).Substring(un.date.Length -4)
        // un.jourMois = "jeu., 19 septembre 2019"
        // un.jourMois = (un.date).Subtring(un.date.Length xxx)
        //un.moisMots =  "jeu., 19 septembre 2019"
        //un.moisMots = (un.date).Subtring(un.date.Length xxx)
        //un.moisChiffre = (** Here goes the comparaison to the dictionary **)

        // At Last 
        //e.dateReel = (The combinaison of the int of the year, month et day of the month)
        //e.dateReel = (e.annee + e.jourMois + e.moisChiffre);

        }
        
//Checking the status of the event if there place it send me a sms message
        foreach (Date d in lstDate)
        {
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(d.url);


            var xpathStatut = "//*[@id='event-page']/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div";
            var locationStatut = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpathStatut);
            var statut = locationStatut.InnerText;

            

            if (statut.IndexOf("Complet") <= 0)
            {
                if (sMessage == "")
                    sMessage = "Il reste de la place pour";
                sMessage += d.date + " ";

            }
        }
        if (sMessage.Length > 0)
        {
            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

            var message = MessageResource.Create(
                body: sMessage,
                from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("-------"),
                to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("------------")
            );

            Console.WriteLine("Message envoyé" + message.Sid);

        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

FULL CODE 2/2 - Classe Date:

```
class Date
{
    public string date;
    public string statut;
    public string url;
    public string moisMots;
    public int moisChiffre;
    public string jourMois;
    public string annee;
    public string dateReel;

    public Date(string Date, string  Statut, string Url)
        {
        date = Date;
        statut = Statut;
        url = Url;

        }
}
```

Comment: Redirected from Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229031/compare-a-dictionary-in-c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the month from a string, [`DateTime.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse) can be used :

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr");

var date = DateTime.Parse("jeu., 19 septembre 2019", culture);

int year = date.Year, month = date.Month, day = date.Day; // 2019, 9, 19
```

For more reliable code, [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse) and [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact) can be used.

Comment: Thank you very much, it simple and right. Is there a way to use the DateTime.Parse to get the year and the day of the month ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for a way to lookup a value in a dictionary from a key. You can use the `dictionary[key]` syntax:

```cs
IDictionary<string, int> dictMonth = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dictMonth.Add("Janvier", 1);
dictMonth.Add("Février", 2);
dictMonth.Add("Mars", 3);

string myMonth = "Février"; //comes from your parsed data, for example.
int monthNumber = dictMonth[myMonth]; //lookup value in dictionary
//monthNumber is now equal to 2
```

You should check that that the key you're looking for exists in the dictionary by using the `ContainsKey` method, otherwise `dictMonth[myMonth]` will throw an exception if `myMonth` is not in `dictMonth`.

Comment: _TryGetValue_ might even be better than _ContainsKey_ as you immediately get the value, so you could compare it to the value from another dictionary.